# C cleaning up on error/termination

Tags: c, memory

I run a bunch of `malloc`s in sequence, and check each time to make sure it was successful. Something like this:

```c
typedef struct {
    int *aray; 
    char *string;
} mystruct;

mystruct *mystruct_init(int length)
{
    mystruct *foo = malloc(sizeof(int *));
    if (!foo) exit(1);

    foo->array = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    if (!foo->array) exit(1);

    foo->string = malloc(length * sizeof(char));
    if (!foo->string) exit(1);

    return foo;
}
```

So when a `malloc` fails, the program exits without freeing the previous ones. What are some techniques to make sure that in case something fails, the program exits safely with all the allocated memory freed?

Comment: Are you *really sure* you want to support platforms (read: bare metal or at minimum no MMU/virtual memory and a common heap) where those are not automatically freed by the system on program exit?

Comment: Dedup is correct that any real OS will free all the memory allocated to your program when it quits, regardless of how. But I applaud your effort to get into the hablt of not relying on that--programs often become modules of other programs, and then it matters.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Any module which calls exit / abort on its own (unless clearly documented to do so for really good reasons, or when it detects an impossible condition) is already beyond hope.

Comment: The technique is to free everything you allocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're designing a driver that runs as part of the OS, you'll need to take care of this more carefully. In this case, `goto` is often used. For example

```
mystruct *mystruct_init(int length)
{
    mystruct *foo = malloc(sizeof(int *));
    if (!foo) goto FOO_FAIL;

    foo->array = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    if (!foo->array) goto ARRAY_FAIL;

    foo->string = malloc(length * sizeof(char));
    if (!foo->string) goto STRING_FAIL;

    return foo;

    STRING_FAIL:
        free(foo->array);
    ARRAY_FAIL:
        free(foo);
    FOO_FAIL:
        REPORT_ERROR; // user defined behavior
    return NULL;
}
```

So if, say, `foo->string` is not allocated successfully, `foo->array` and `foo` will be freed accordingly. If `foo->array` fails, only `foo` will be freed. When any of these fails, the function returns NULL, which allows the caller to check the return value and decide next step.

Answer (score 3):

Most modern operating systems would free the right memory after the process terminates after calling `exit(...)`. These operating systems include:

- all Unix variants, including Linux and Mac OS X
- all Windows versions
- all DOS variants

Answer (score 2):

Here's one of my favorite tricks:

```
do {
    a = malloc(...);
    if (!a) break;

    b = malloc(...);
    if (!b) {
        free(a);
        break;
    }
} while (0);

if (!a) {
    ...
    return;
}

...

free(b);
free(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do post-mortem cleanup then you can register an atexit handler

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html

BTW I am not saying its easy to do (or correct)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way too, I think it's the cleanest way to do it and I use it very often, but to return from a function, not to exit from the program since it is true that system will free memory at exit.

By the way your program as is will give segmentation fault, since you are not allocating enough space for `foo`.

```
typedef struct {
    int *aray; 
    char *string;
} mystruct;

mystruct *mystruct_init(int length)
{
    mystruct *foo = malloc(sizeof(mystruct)); // you need to allocate space for string too
    if (!foo)
        return NULL;
    memset(foo, 0, sizeof(mystruct)); // initialize all members to NULL

    foo->array = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    if (!foo->array)
        goto abort;

    foo->string = malloc(length * sizeof(char));
    if (!foo->string)
        goto abort;

    return foo;
abort:
    if (foo->array)
        free(foo->array);
    if (foo->string)
        free(foo->string);
    return NULL;
}
```

now in the calling function you can do it cleanly like

```
mystruct *foo;

foo = mystruct_init(length /* assuming this is declared and set. */);
if (!foo)
    exit(1);
```

Comment: also `sizeof(char)` is always equal to `1`.